# How to make checkout a static block / have identifier like static blocks or pages?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, static-block, cms-pages

Can I make magento checkout to have an identifier/ID like static blocks and pages?

What's the best practice or solution to do this?

I'm currently calling out magento pages / static blocks through API calls on my vuejs PWA by "identifiers".

Example:

## Cms content

```
<h2>
  Cms page content
</h2>
<p>
  (by identifier, it handles current store view if multistore is enable)
</p>
<cms-data :identifier="'about-us'" :type="'Page'"/>

<h2>Cms block content
</h2>
<p>
  (by identifier, it handles current store view if multistore is enable)
</p>
<cms-data :identifier="'contact-us-info'" :type="'Block'"/>
```